# Query Google Play for paid app price from other app

Tags: android, google-play

From a promo screen in the lite version of my app (com.example.lite), how can I display the price of the paid version (com.example) to the user?
Note: this is not an inapp purchase, it has a link to the full version in the Google Play store

Comment: Unless there is something in https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/ there may not be a documented and supported option for that.